# ASP.NET Get textbox value in gridview when button which is outside gridview is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview to load dynamic textbox, this code is create dynamic textbox when gridView_RowDataBound event:

```
TextBox txtCountry = new TextBox();
txtCountry.ID = "txtDisplayOrder";
txtCountry.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["DISPORDR"].ToString();
e.Row.Cells[9].Controls.Add(txtCountry);
```

After run this event, gridview.Rows[0].Cells[9].Controls.Count is 1

I have LinkedButton which is put outside gridview, when button is click, I catch it in server, but when I try to get value from textbox in gridview.Rows[0].Cells[9].Controls.Count is 0 and I cannot get value.

I need your help

Comment: If you add a control in code, you need to re add it on post back before you can retrieve the value. Looking at the code you have posted it is not clear why yopu are doing it this way rather than just putting it in the markup and databinding.

Comment: If I do that, how can I retrieve new value from user input?

Comment: If you add a control of the correct type with the correct id, in the init event i think, then you can retrieve the value later in the page lifecycle.

Comment: Can you show me more about this? If I write function to load data in PostBack, I will overwrite it's data or I misunderstood

Comment: You don't normally re-bind data on postback for exactly that reason, your data binding code sits within an `if(!IsPostback)` block

Comment: I know that, so I don't understand what your mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't add/remove controls dynamically , this is bad practice. Add the control in the grid always and  set the visibility of the control `FALSE`, when you click the button just found the control and make the visibility `TRUE`. In this case you will not have this problems !

Controls which are `Visible=false` on serverside are not rendered at all on client-side. This is the best apporach.

Comment: I would not say it is bad practice as such, it is useful when you don't know the number and type of controls you want on the page at compile time.